# MS Access + NZ() function with empty table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am trying to add values from two different tables, but one of the tables is completely empty. I know the Nz() function is meant to convert Null values to a different value, i.e. 0, but the problem I am having is the table doesn't have any data, so Nz() doesn't work.

Is there a way I can add the values of two tables together if one table is Null? I know it seems pointless, and eventually the table will have values, but for the sake of this week's reports, I need to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is to do with your query. Try something on the lines of:

```
SELECT Nz(t1.[Field1],0) + Nz(t2.[Field1],0) As Added 
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

The important point is LEFT JOIN, which will include all records from t1, even if there is no match in t2.

Comment: You need to use `Nz(Field, 0)` because it you omit the second parameter, `Nz` will return an empty string.

Comment: You think I would have learned these things by now. Thanks Remou!

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `Nz()` function is not available outside of the Access UI. Here's an alternative approach that avoids `Nz()`:

```
SELECT t1.Field1 + t2.Field1 AS Added 
  FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
UNION
SELECT 0 AS Added 
  FROM t2
HAVING COUNT(*) = 0;
```